# Teasers/summaries don't show when body begins with picture

Tags: media, wysiwyg, nodes, entities

I have a blog content type which uses a WYSIWYG editor and allows media to be inserted.  Usually things work out fine, and the blog page shows a list of nice trimmed teasers and/or summaries.  But when the blog post begins with a picture, the teasers and/or summaries don't show up on the blog page.  Instead, there is just a --- where the text would normally be.

I tried deleting the

tags around the image, but it didn't help.

Any advice? (We have to continue using the WYSIWYG editor/media insert, so that part can't change, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [How to Add a WYSIWYG Editor to a "Text with Summary" Field](http://theunraveler.com/blog/2012/drupal-7-how-add-wysiwyg-editor-text-summary-field/) if it works for you.